# How do I create a single controller for two models?

Tags: view, model, controller, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have two controllers for my MVC structure project. One is going to show a list of expenses and other lists of open sources but I have two different routes for that. How do I create a controller for just one view which will show both lists of expenses and open sources from just one controller?
 What's the best way to solve this problem?

```
defmodule DashboardtaskWeb.OpensourceController do
  use DashboardtaskWeb, :controller

  alias Dashboardtask.Task
  alias Dashboardtask.Task.Opensource

  def index(conn, _params) do
    opensources = Task.list_opensources()
    render(conn, "index.html", opensources: opensources)
  end

  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Task.change_opensource(%Opensource{})
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"opensource" => opensource_params}) do
    case Task.create_opensource(opensource_params) do
      {:ok, opensource} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Opensource created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.opensource_path(conn, :show, opensource))

      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    opensource = Task.get_opensource!(id)
    render(conn, "show.html", opensource: opensource)
  end

  def edit(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    opensource = Task.get_opensource!(id)
    changeset = Task.change_opensource(opensource)
    render(conn, "edit.html", opensource: opensource, changeset: changeset)
  end

  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "opensource" => opensource_params}) do
    opensource = Task.get_opensource!(id)

    case Task.update_opensource(opensource, opensource_params) do
      {:ok, opensource} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Opensource updated successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.opensource_path(conn, :show, opensource))

      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "edit.html", opensource: opensource, changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    opensource = Task.get_opensource!(id)
    {:ok, _opensource} = Task.delete_opensource(opensource)

    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Opensource deleted successfully.")
    |> redirect(to: Routes.opensource_path(conn, :index))
  end
end
```

For expenses controller, it's the same. I was thinking to use polymorphic association for this. Do you think it's the best idea?

Comment: Why are you thinking of using a polymorphic association? How are the two resources associated?

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a new table for that. Where I can store there id's and create a controller for new model?